# how to convert string to Date Format and assign it to a string variable?

Tags: c#

I am getting DateTime from DB as '21/10/2018 04:08:23' as a string. Now I would like to convert it to MMDDYYYY format and assign it to a string variable (GridView).

Please some one suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: If your object from the database is a `DateTime`, why are you converting it to a string in a format other than the one you want? And I would assume that the grid view control you're using allows you to supply a format string, meaning you wouldn't need to convert it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` and a date format string.

Input: `21/10/2018 04:08:23`

```
string FormatDate(string input) {
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return date.ToString("MMddyyyy");
}
```

Output:
    `10212018`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` and provide the pattern of how to parse the string.

Something like:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("21/10/2018 04:08:23", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
    }
}
```

Then when you call the `ToString()` you provide the pattern you want to output

**RESULT**

```
10212018
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1vnKRP)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
string dbDate = "21/10/2018 04:08:23";
var formattedDate = DateTime.Parse(dbDate).ToString("MMDDYYYY");
```

Answer (score -1):

This method will converts the specified string representation of a date and time to an equivalent date and time value

`string iDate = "05/05/2005";`

`DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(oDate).ToString("MMDDYYYY");`

Let me know if you run into some trouble

Comment: The OP is already getting a DateTime from the database, and this is not a normal way to format a date as a string (use `oDate.ToString("desired format goes here")`), nor is it in the format OP wants.